# R CMD check warning: bad markup (extra space?)

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen

[This Roxygen issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/337) refers to this warning too (from running `R CMD check` - or in my case `devtools::check()`) but I think that something else is causing this warning in my case, as `Roxygen: list(wrap = TRUE)` is not in my package DESCRIPTION file for a data package.

The full warning is:

````
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: bad markup (extra space?) at railtrails.Rd:13:26
See ‘/private/var/folders/95/z6jql6w546vd0brdwm722s5r0000gn/T/RtmpJ7q9ou/railtrails.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.

checking Rd files ... WARNING
prepare_Rd: bad markup (extra space?) at railtrails.Rd:13:26
```

Here is what seems to be the offending code:

```
#' Rail-trail trail data
#'
#' Information and reviews for rail-trails in the United States
#'
#' @source https://www.traillink.com/
#' @format Data frame with columns
#' \describe{
#' \item{name}{Name of rail trail}
#' \item{distance}{distance (miles)}
#' \item{surface}{surface material}
#' \item{category}{trail category}
#' \item{mean review rating}
#' \item{description}{text description of trail}
#' \item{n_reviews}{number of reviews}
#' \item{raw_reviews}{list column with a vector of reviews}
#' }
#' @importFrom tibble tibble
#' @examples
#' railtrails
#'
#' # to expand vector of review ratings in raw_reviews column:
#' library(tidyr)
#' railtrails <- railtrails %>% unnest(raw_reviews)

"railtrails"
````

Thank you for the help. The package is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/railtrails).

Comment: that line shld be: `\item{mean review rating}{}` OR follow the other `\item` lines and have the column name and the description (looks like you forgot the column name

Comment: And you have a PR with said fix (I added the column name)

Comment: Thank you! (I also just happened to add an acknowledgment thanking you for feedback you provided earlier!).